# How to integrate spring-integration in an existing spring-mvc application?

Tags: spring-mvc, web-applications, integration, spring-integration

i have a typical spring-webmvc application (with REST request mapped in Controller's method that call a Service's method) and I would like to use spring-integration to manage the asynchronous functionality (e.g. mail, sms, notification...).

*For example i would like that a Service Component after insert in my DB publish a message in spring-integration context channel in asycn mode so that the control return immediataly at the Controller to return an http response to the client.*

**How to integrate "spring-integration" in my existing spring-mvc application?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply inject a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) into your controller. Define an interface, declare an `<int:gateway id="toMail"/>` and use normal Spring bean injection techniques to inject the gateway (as an instance of your interface) into the controller.

If you don't want to wait for a a reply; set the method return value to `void` and, if you make the first channel (the gateway's `default-request-channel`) an [Executor Channel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel), the message will be handed off to another thread and the gateway will returm immediately.
[Configuring an Executor Channel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel).